# Is there a way to know the status of panda `to_csv` for very long databases?

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas I have a very large dataframe which I am trying to write to a CSV file. It is taking a very long time ( a couple hours and not finished) and I am wondering if there's any way to check the % finished in this command.

I looked up all the arguments in `to_csv` and there doesn't seem to be anything to help

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

`pd.to_csv('thefile.csv', chunksize =1000 )`

I would like any time of status, chunk number, etc.

Comment: A couple of hours sounds a lot. May I ask why you want to store that amount of data in a csv-file? Have you considered using a database instead? Or if you want to reuse it in Python, pickle?

Comment: I need to keep in mind disk space, so I picked CSV. I've heard that after compressed CSV takes up smallest disk space, if this is incorrect would love to hear any additional information.

Comment: what kind of data types do you have in your DF?

Comment: I would recommend to use either Parquet or HDF5 binary formats - they are __much__ faster, all Pandas dtypes are natively supported, they support fast compression, etc. I'm using CSV only there are no other alternatives

Comment: I have text files, will look into parquet, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is taking hours to write a data frame, then as @AntonvBR suggested you should look for better alternatives.

If you still want to stick with csv, you can split your data frame and write it. This way you will also get to know how it progresses. Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_split = np.array_split(df, 10) # Choose a bigger number

for i in range(0,10): # Use the number of splits
    print(i)
    df_split[i].to_csv("the_file.csv", mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that you could append. In the docs under mode it has 'mode : str
Python write mode, default ‘w’.' which I didn't know what it meant .